# Search for a string but search another set of strings before and after that

Tags: xml, linux

I am trying to search for a string "LogFatal2Sys" but I will search for the string "ValNameList" BEFORE and AFTER that and put a comment tag before and after the lines of "ValNameList" lines. So basically, there are many "ValNameList" blocks inside my xml so i need to comment out this portion of the xml using set of Unix commands. Can someone help me?

```
    <ValNameList
                    xmlns="http://www.oblix.com"
                    ListName="LogFatal2Sys">
                    <NameValPair
                            ParamName="LOG_LEVEL"
                            Value="LOGLEVEL_FATAL">
                    </NameValPair>
                    <NameValPair
                            ParamName="LOG_WRITER"
                            Value="SysLogWriter">
                    </NameValPair>
                    <NameValPair
                            ParamName="LOG_STATUS"
                            Value="On">
                    </NameValPair>
    </ValNameList>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now I understand what you need basically is to comment out these XML blocks. You can do that by using the sed command as following:

```
cat your_xml_file | sed 's/<ValNameList>/<!-- <ValNameList>/g' | sed 's/<\/ValNameList>/<\/ValNameList>-->/g'
```

This basically looks for every ValNameList block and insert an XML comment start at the beginning, and do the same for the block closing.

Comment: basically, I am particular with the "ValNameList" block with ListName="LogFatal2Sys" since there are several "ValNameList" in the rest of the xml file and I don't want to comment them all out. Do you have another idea?